# Replace text in square brackets but not in the ones immediately after them

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some HTML similar to this one:

```
<input value="" name="test[0][test_inner_one]" type="text">
<input value="" name="test[0][test_inner_two]" type="text">
<input value="" name="test[0][test_inner_three]" type="text">
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace only the `0` with something else, but I can't figure the regex.
So, for example, after replacing, it should look like:

```
<input value="" name="test[1][test_inner_one]" type="text">
<input value="" name="test[1][test_inner_two]" type="text">
<input value="" name="test[1][test_inner_three]" type="text">
```

The idea for the whole thing is I'm cloning HTML, and the `0` and the text before it will not be static, so for example it will not be always `test[0]` but it will be in the following format `some_text[index][some_other_text]`, I need to replace only the "index".
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: `str.replace('test[0]', 'test[1]');`??????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you can simply use this:

```
var newName = name.replace(/\[0]/, '[1]');
```

Or even more simply, get rid of the regular expression:

```
var newName = name.replace('[0]', '[1]');
```

**Update**

To replace any pairs of braces which contain only numbers, use something like this:

```
var newName = name.replace(/\[\d+]/, '[1]');
```

To replace only the content of the first pair of brackets, regardless of what it contains, you can use this

```
var newName = name.replace(/\[.*?]/, '[1]');
```

This works because the replace method will only replace the first match found (unless  the `g` flag is enabled in your regular expression).

Comment: Forgot to mention, the text will not always be zero, updated question.

Comment: Yes and the text after that will always be text. :)

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks for the edit, but it isn't actually necessary to escape the `]`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It isn't? But `]` is a regex char? Or does it not matter if we don't have a starting bracket?

Comment: @h2ooooooo If it's not closing a character class the regex engine treats it like a literal `]` character.

Comment: I actually used `/\[\d]/g` because I need to replace multiple lines of HTML at once, but thanks for asking if it will always be a number, that pushed me into the right direction :)

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov You might want to use `/\[\d+]/` if you need to handle `[100]` or something like that. Also, I'd avoid performing regex on whole blocks of HTML. It might not be as efficient (in some cases), but it's probably safer to walk the DOM and make the changes as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to replace the first occurence, simply let out the `/g` modifier:

```
var str = 'my[bar][string]';

str = str.replace(/\[.*?\]/, '[foo]');

console.log(str); //my[foo][string]
```

Autopsy:

- `\[` a literal `[` character - we have to escape this as `[` is a reserved regex char
- `.*?` lazy match. Match as little as possible
- `\]` a literal `]` character - we have to escape this as `]` is a reserved regex char